# Asserting the presence of scrollbar using Selenium (webdriver java cucumber)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, cucumber

I have a responsive website I need to test. If the website goes to the window size of a Tablet, I want the test to check if there is a horizontal scrollbar. According to the design they can never be present on a tablet.

Does anyone have a piece of pseudo-code to assert the presence of a horizontal scrollbar using Selenium Webdriver Java Cucumber?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can test this with `javascriptExecutor`:

Vertical scrollbar:

```
boolean scrollBarPresent = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;");
```

Horizontal scrollbar:

```
boolean scrollBarPresent = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollWidth>document.documentElement.clientWidth;");
```